# Face Mesh Disappears when I bind it to a Facial Rig

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, geometry

I am trying to create a facial rig with the FaceIt Plugin from Blender Market.

I'm trying to bind the facial mesh to the rig it created. I'm finding that the face mesh disappears whenever I try and bind it.

**Before binding the mesh**

[image]

**After Binding the Mesh**

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The disappearing of your mesh is actually most probably just a huge difference in scale.
Faceit scales the mesh and armature during binding. Older versions of Faceit applied the scale after binding. This is not happening anymore. By upgrading the Faceit add-on to a more recent version, you should be able to bind again.

By the way: What you are trying to do is binding a mesh that is already bound to an armature to a new armature (the Faceit armature). Faceit will overwrite the weights. You should work on a duplicate, as described here: https://faceit-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/workaround/